# PHP MySQLi persistent connections with SSL

Tags: php, ssl, mysqli, persistent

I am having problem with configuring persistent MySQLi connections over ssl. Any suggestions are appreciated.

W/o persistent connections:

```
$flags = MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL;
$link = new mysqli();
$link->ssl_set(null, null, null, null, "RC4-MD5");
if ($link->real_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port, null, $flags)) {
    $r = $link->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'");
    var_dump($r->fetch_row());
}
```

the the output is

```
array(2) {
   [0]=> string(10) "Ssl_cipher"
   [1]=> string(18) "RC4-MD5"
}
```

With persistent connections:

```
$flags = MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL;
$link = new mysqli();
$link->ssl_set(null, null, null, null, "RC4-MD5");
if ($link->real_connect('p:' . $host, $user, $pass, $db, $port, null, $flags)) {
    $r = $link->query("SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher'");
    var_dump($r->fetch_row());
}
```

the the output is

```
array(2) {
   [0]=> string(10) "Ssl_cipher"
   [1]=> string(0) ""
}
```

UPDATE: I believe this is a php bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55283 - basically ssl_set() is ignored for persistent connections and in my case due to server config this downgraded the connection to be non-ssl.

Comment: Somehow I don't think that ssl over persistent will work. There's no guarantee that the next user of the connection would have (or be alowed to use) the same SSL credentials.

Comment: From what you describe in your question I would assume that persistent connections and SSL do not go together. Can you please add your PHP version to the question?

Comment: Actually, I am very confident that this is a php bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55283

Answer (score 0):

You have to first run mysqli::ssl_set before real_connect.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ssl-set.php

Comment: Ops, bad copy/paste. There is ssl_set()